# Finding Mclaurin series for $1-\cos (x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I was trying to find the Mclaurin series for $1-\cos (x)$. I know that 
$$1-\cos(x) = 1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

This brought me to 
$$1-\cos(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

Since the first term in the $1-\cos(x)$ series is $-1$, so you get $1-1=0$, and then multiply in the $-1$ in $-\cos(x)$, however the solution set says $$1-\cos(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

Did I get the right answer? Is my thinking correct?

Also, isn't $(-1)^{-1} = -1$ ?

Comment: Exactly, so $(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^{n-1}$, and your solution is the same as the solution set.

Comment: $(-1)^{n-1}$ and $(-1)^{n+1}$ alternate between $-1$ and $1$ and since for $n=1$ they are both 1, using either  $(-1)^{n-1}$ or $(-1)^{n+1}$ will make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-1)^{n+1} = (-1)^{n-1} \times (-1)^2 = (-1)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Expand both your series and the solution set series. You'll see that the terms are all the same.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \frac{-1^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{-1^3x^4}{4!}+\frac{-1^4x^6}{6!}...$$ which is equal to
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{-x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}...$$
Now,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{-1^0x^2}{2!}+\frac{-1^1x^4}{4!}+\frac{-1^2x^6}{6!}...$$
which comes out to be the same series again.